# iOS 7 - Identify segue that called view to unwind correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIViewController that can be presented by two different other views. It's a search form that act exactly the same for both views.

Let's say View1 and View2 can perform segues that present an instance of SearchView. How could I know which view presented SearchView so that I can perform an unwind segue that is linked to the corresponding action?

As both View1 and View2 are TabViews, I don't want to use a navigationController in each of them as I find it a little bit of overpower for a simple task.

In this example:

View1.m

```
-(IBAction)didClickButton:
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"searchSegue1"];
}
```

View2.m

```
-(IBAction)didClickButton:
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"searchSegue2"];
}
```

SearchView.m

```
// Here is where I should know which segue to call
if (***ConditionToSegue1***)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToSegue1"];

else if (***ConditionToSegue2***)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToSegue2"];
```

What is this condition? Is the best way to do it to just set a property of SearchView in the prepareForSegue methods that tells me what view that originated the call? Please keep in mind this I do no wish to use a NavigationController.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SearchView.h add  the line `@property (nonatomic) int tag`.

Then in View1.m add the following method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"searchSegue1"])
        [segue.destinationViewController setValue:1 forKey:@"tag"];
}
```

Do the same thing in View2.m but replace 1 with 2. Then change your if statement to:

```
if (self.tag == 1)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToSegue1"];
else if (self.tag == 2)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToSegue2"];
```

Comment: This is a good approach. I thought of using something like this but found out a better one that seems to work.

Comment: Nope, my "something better" didn't work completely. Marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know whether you are using storyboard or programatically creating storyboard for PERFORMING SEGUE.

```
    1.If you directly connect the segue through the click button(one view controller to another view controller),you don't need to write your above coding.Just it is enough to give segue name. 
            click->SHOW THE ATTRIBUTES OF RIGHT SIDE UTILITY AREA.
                 ->NOW YOU CAN SEE THE STORYBOARD SEGUE WITH-IDENTIFIER,STYLE 
                 ->IN IDENTIFIER TEXTFIELD JUST GIVE YOUR SEGUE NAME(WHATEVER YOU WANT)
                   (IN STYLE-PUSH IS DEFAULT IF YOU CONNECT THE SEGUE AS A PUSH)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation it may be as simple as `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];`

Check out this blog post near the end that's titled **Unwind Segues**.

http://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards

You can wire up an action to the `Exit` component on the Storyboard which will do the unwinding for you.

```
-(IBAction)reset:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that there is an easy answer to this. Apparently, if I create an unwind action on both view controllers named just the same, I can create just one unwind segue for both of them as well.

If I perform this segue on the SearchView it calls the correct action depending on who presented it.

This seems to work for now, I don't really know why or how it happens. Would appreciate if anyone could explain.

**UPDATE:**
Nope, it doesn't work as expected. Although the correct view is presented both actions are called, resulting in unwanted behavior.